# how to find if a bound intersects/contains multiple polygon in leaflet

Tags: geometry, leaflet, polygons

Basically I want to use zoombox to select multiple polygons.

What I'm doing now is to use leaflet's built in `intersects` function to compare the bound of zoombox (which is a rectangle) to every other polygons in the map.

This solution have two issues:

1. It's slow. for 100+ polygons with 10's to 100's coordinates each, this could take more than a sec to find all intersecting/overlapping polygons.
2. It does not work for concave polygons. Because `leaflet`'s `intersects` function is pretty naive, which treat each polygon to be a rectangle and compare their SW and NE coordinate. (which also explains why its slow to find intersection, because it has to go through all coordinates everytime to find max/min of them).

I guess I can save the min/max of each polygon during initialization phase, though it would increase the startup time by few seconds, which is not a small number for a web app.

But for the concave intersection detection, I cannot think of any good way to solve it without causing big performance hit. A user clearly won't want to drag, wait for few seconds, and saw the selected ones being highlighted. 
A naive solution I can think of would be check intersections with all the edges of each polygons, but that would take a long time since the polygon is pretty complex with 10s - 100s of edges each.

Comment: Displaying 100+ polygons starts being a lot. As for intersecting arbitrary shaped polygons, you would be interested in [Turf](http://turfjs.org/).

Comment: I tried turf, but it's still very slow. The only thing I found which is fast is openlayer's box selection, but I don't think it can work with leaflet